# Copying local folder to a git branch copies the folder to all branches?

Tags: git, repository, branch, cp

I have a local folder on my computer "local_d"

I have a repo with 2 branches "master", "hipster"

I do some operations on "local_d" with a script and want to copy this "local_d" to the "hipster" branch

I am currently active in the (*hipster) branch but outside the git repo (e.g. home folder)

When I do:

```
cp -r ~/local_d ~/git/repo
```

"local_d" exists both in "master" and the "hipster" branches???

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is local_d showing up as untracked? What does git status report on both branches?

Comment: Pretty sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40324367/1290731) is a dup, anybody knows a better one feel free to just peg it.

Answer (score 0):

> "local_d" exists both in "master" and the "hipster" branches???

No.  It's not in *any* branches.  It's not in the *repository* at all.

"But I can see it, it's right here", I hear you say.  Yes.  The thing is "right here" *is not in the repository*.  **The files you can see and work with are not in Git.**

This is probably the very first thing you should know, *before* you start using Git.  Git does not store *files:* Git stores *commits*.  Commits then *contain* files, but not in their ordinary, every-day format.  The files stored inside Git commits are in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form, and nothing but Git can read them and *nothing*—not even  Git itself—can *overwrite* them.  This makes them quite useless for getting work done.  (This sort of thing, where the version-controlled files can't be used directly, is true of many version control systems: Git is not particularly special here.)

What this means for you is that in order to use files from some Git commit, you first have Git *copy* those files, extracting them out of the commit, changing them from their internal Git-only format into files that you can see and use.  These plain ordinary everyday files, which are useful for getting work done, are *not the files in the commit*.  They're just plain ordinary everyday files.

The *committed* files are safely tucked away inside the commits.  Git works with the commits.  Git can also make *new* commits, and to do that, you'll want to have Git copy any updates you made.  To get those updates *into* Git you must use `git add` on those files.<sup>1</sup>

What *this* means for you is that whatever you do to the copied-out, useful files in *your* work area, that's not *in Git*.  Copying a bunch of files into your working tree is fine, but it doesn't put them into anything other than *your* working tree.  Git doesn't save them anywhere, but it doesn't *remove* them either.  They're *yours*, not Git's.  Git just leaves them there.

There *are* some files in your work area that *did* come out of Git, when you ran `git checkout` (or in Git 2.23 and later, `git switch`).  When you pick some *other* commit to `git checkout`, Git takes *those* files *out* of your work area, and puts in the files from the *other* commit instead.  As long as all the `local_d/*` files aren't in *either* commit, though, they just keep sitting there.

Once you use `git add` to tell Git: *these files should go into the next commit I make*—this copies them into what I like to refer to as your *proposed next commit;* note that you haven't actually *made* this commit yet—*now* Git knows about these files and will start doing things with them.  But until then, Git just assumes that you made this extra stuff and would like to keep it there while Git works around it.

---

<sup>1</sup>While there are some shortcuts for this, I believe it's not a good idea to learn them first, for multiple reasons that I won't go into here.